# If we have $m$ indistinguishable objects how many ways is it possible to put them in $n$ indistinguihable positions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

if we have $m$ indistinguishable objects, how many ways is it possible to put them in $n$ indistinguishable  positions? (for 2 cases 1: without empty position allowed 2: empty positions are allowed.)

We already know that if objects were distinct and the positions are undistinguishable, the number is called Stirling number $S(m,n)$ (without empty positions allowed).

Comment: The topic is called [partitions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) In Case $1$, it is partitions of $m$ into $n$ parts. In Case $2$, it is into $\le n$ parts. The subject of partitions is quite complicated. I hope the link gives you a useful start.

Comment: What if we generalize the problem to include multi-sets.... like you try to find how many ways there are to put $m$ (identical) pebbles inside of $n$ (identical) hats, but wait for it.... you can put the hats inside one another and pebbles may fit in different parts of the hats.... now that's crazy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elaborating on @Andre's answer, let $p_k(n)$ denote the number of ways to write the natural number $n$ as the sum of exactly $k$ natural numbers, in nonincreasing order.  For example, $p_2(3)=1$ because $3=2+1$ is the only such sum.  $p_2(4)=2$ because $4=3+1$ and $4=2+2$ are the two different such sums.  We also have $p_3(3)=1$ since $3=1+1+1$ is the only such sum, and $p_3(4)=1$ since $4=2+1+1$ is the only such sum.  We have $p_4(3)=0$ since there is no such sum with four parts.  We call these functions  **partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts**.  We may also add up $p_1(n)+p_2(n)+p_3(n)+\cdots$ to get all the **partitions of $n$** (into any number of parts).  This is represented by $p(n)$.

Now I'll explain why these functions are relevant to your problem. Suppose I have $m$ identical marbles, and $n$ identical bowls.  I place the marbles in the bowls.  Then, since the marbles are identical, all I can tell about each bowl is how many marbles are inside it.  So, perhaps I have a bowl with 4 marbles, a bowl with 2 marbles, a bowl with 7 marbles.  However, the bowls all look the same, so I may as well arrange the bowls so that each bowl has at least as many marbles as the next bowl.  That is, I'll put the bowl with 7 marbles first, then the bowl with 4 marbles, then the bowl with 2 marbles.  We can think of this as $13=7+4+2$.  If we want to put our $13$ marbles into exactly three bowls, and each bowl gets at least one marble, then this is bijective with partitions of $13$ into exactly $3$ parts, i.e. $p_3(13)$.  If instead we want to put our $13$ marbles into exactly three bowls, and some bowls may be empty, then we want to count $13=7+4+2$, but also $13=9+4 (+0)$.  Hence this case is counted by $p_3(13)+p_2(13)+p_1(13)$.  Lastly, if we have an unlimited number of bowls at our disposal (although we'll never need more than 13), then we want $p_1(13)+p_2(13)+p_3(13)+p_4(13)+\cdots =p(13)$.

Many identities are known about these partition functions, although in my opinion not as many as for binomial coefficients.  You can read about some of them on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29).  Some samples are:

- The sequence $p(n)$ has the generating function $\prod_{k\ge 1}=\frac{1}{1-x^k}$
- If $n\equiv 4\pmod{5}$, then $p(n)$ is a multiple of $5$ (due to Ramanujan)
- $p(n)\approx \frac{1}{4n\sqrt{3}}e^{\left(\pi \sqrt{2n/3}\right)}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ (also due to Ramanujan, but with Hardy and independently by Uspensky)
- The number of partitions where the largest part has size exactly $k$ is equal to $p_k(n)$.

Comment: general statement is correct. but recursion is wrong because in wikipedia it's considered without restricted position also we have for $p_3(5)=p_4(5)+p_3(2)$, $p_3(5)=2$ because $1+2+2=5=3+1+1$ but $p_4(5)=1, 5=2+1+1+1, p_3(2)=0$ then $1 \not = 2$---- if $p_k(n)=p_{k-1}(n)+p_k(n-k)$ it's seem correct how to prove it? for example$ p_3(5)=2, p_2(5)=2$ also for $p_5(11)=p_4(11)+p_5(6)---10=9+1$

Comment: I'm sorry, this was my mistake.  In that section Wikipedia uses $p(k,n)$ to denote partitions where each part is of size $\ge k$, which is different from $p_k(n)$.  I've deleted the incorrect parts of my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let us call $A_k(n)$ the number of partitions of $n$ identical objects into $k$ identical boxes allowing empty boxes. If we do not allow empty boxes we simply have $A_k(n-k)$ since we first put one object in each box and then partition the rest without any restrictions.

Now, additionally, consider the number $A_{k,l}(n)$ which is the number of partitions of $n$ objects into $k$ boxes that can fit no more than $l$ objects each. This is the number of Young's diagrams of $n$ squares that fit into a $k\times l$ rectangle. So, $A_{k,l}(n)=A_{l,k}(n)$.

To calculate $A_{k,l}(n)$ consider first choosing how many objects to put in the box with the most objects. Let's say we chose to put $j$ objects in that box. To count how many options we have given that choice we simply need $A_{k-1,j}(n-j)$, since we have $j$ fewer objects to put in boxes, one fewer box to put objects in, and we know that none of these boxes has more than $j$ objects. Therefore, we have the following recursion relation:

$$A_{k,l}(n) = \sum_{j=1}^{l} A_{k-1,j}(n-j)\text.$$

Note that $A_k(n)=A_{k,n}(n)$ so we have our answer.